# Showing a function can not be continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I want to show that there does not exist a continuous function $f(x)$ satisfying the following criteria. 
$$
\int_0^{1/2} f(x) dx - \int_{1/2}^1 f(x) dx = 1
$$
When we restrict $\displaystyle \|f(x)\| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \leq 1$.

You can geometrically observe that you can become arbitrarily close to such a function by looking at potential graphs of $f(x)$, but never actually achieve the desired result without violating continuity of $f(x)$. Can anyone help me out with a concrete argument.

Comment: Hint: You can show $-\frac{1}{2}\le \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx\le \frac{1}{2}$, and similar for the second integral, with equality holding iff $f(x)=-1$ always (on the left) or $f(x)=1$ always (on the right).

Comment: I think this argument would lead to the following $|\int_0^{1/2} f(x) dx - \int_{1/2}^1 f(x) dx | \leq |\int_0^{1/2} f(x) dx |+ |\int_{1/2}^1 f(x) dx| \leq 1/2 + 1/2 = 1.$ We would like to show strict inequality.

Comment: Thank you, sorry my last comment was posted a bit premature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The continuous function $f$ is defined on compact sets, hence attains maximum and minimum by Weierstrass on each of them. It follows the values of both integrals belong to the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$. At this point, the first relation
$$
\int_{[0,1/2]}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}
$$
implies that the minimum (in the interval $[0,1/2]$), is also $1$. Hence $f(x)=1$ on the whole $[0,1/2]$. Similarly on the other part, $f$ should be equal to $-1$. Therefore it cannot be continuous in $1/2$.

Ps. You can consider both interval closed because the value of the integral is equal on (a,b] and [a,b]